# parsing JSON for geolocation

Tags: php, jquery, json

i hope someone can help me with my script. I am trying to parse some geocoordinates.
i cannot get it to work, please what am i doing wrong ?.

```
            function mapping(orig_lat, orig_lng) {
            $(function () {
                //Parse xml with jQuery
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "json_test.php",
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function (json) {
                    _locationset = new Array();
                    for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {
                    var data = json[i],

                    latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
                    name: data.name
                        Marker: null,
                        Distance: null
                    _locationset.push(data);
                    }
```

my Json output is :

```
{"pharmacies":[{"id":"1","name":"Pharmacie 1","adresse":"Adresse 1","long":"-7.630284","lat":"33.590707","phone_number":"1","garde":"yes"},{"id":"2","name":"Pharmacie 2","adresse":"Adresse 2","long":"-7.622344","lat":"33.593137","phone_number":"2","garde":"no"},{"id":"3","name":"Pharmcie 3","adresse":"Adresse 3","long":"-7.623718","lat":"33.597499","phone_number":"3","garde":"yes"}]}
```

any help will be apprecated

Comment: is the json output whats inside json variable? if so, why do you have a for loop?

Comment: well . .i am a noob . reading the documentation, and as i understand, i have to loop through the JSON output to retrieve the different data ?

Comment: according to the structure of your json output,  I suspect `var data = json[i]` is not targetting what you need

Comment: if that is the json then it acts like an obj in js, so you may need a for loop for json.pharmacies.length, have data = json.pharmacies[i]

Comment: take depperm comment in consideration, this is what I wanted to say

Comment: changing data = json.pharmacies[i]  .. doesnt really help much. i guess i am a bt lost

Comment: @mounim, do you know how to log javascript variables in console?

Comment: @whiteletters : a little bit, i tried to debug in consle in my chrome browser, but nothing is showing up really

Answer (score 0):

```
latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.long);
```

Comment: sorry i changed that in my phpmyadmin ( since "long" is a reserved name ).